# UICollectionViewCell loses value on refresh swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The first image shows that whenever I click a cell on the collectionview it will show the ID of the selected cell on the title view of the View Controller:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ2Se.png]
Now my problem is, whenever I sort the title of the collection view, and click a single cell the ID is gone:

[image]
I don't know what to do now, because I cannot find related posts about this. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class MovieCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    private let leftAndRightPadding: CGFloat = 24.0
    private let numberItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
    private let heightAdustment: CGFloat = 90.0

    var movies: [MOVIE]?
    var filteredMovies: [MOVIE]?

    var searchControllerMovie: UISearchController!


    func filterContentForSearchTextMovie(searchText: String) {
        filteredMovies = movies?.filter{
            movie in
            return (movie.movTitle?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
        }
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchControllerMovie = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
        self.searchControllerMovie.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchControllerMovie.searchBar.text = ""
        self.searchControllerMovie.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchControllerMovie.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchControllerMovie.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        searchControllerMovie.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchControllerMovie.searchBar


        //SPACING BETWEEN COLLECTION VIEW CELLS
        let width = (collectionView!.frame.width - leftAndRightPadding) / numberItemsPerRow
        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width + heightAdustment)

        //LOADER
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        fetchMovie()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setupNavBarButtons()
    }

    func setupNavBarButtons() {
        let sortAsc = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "arrow_up")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(sortMovieByAsc))

        let sortDesc = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "arrow_down")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(sortMovieByDesc))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [sortDesc, sortAsc]
    }

    func sortMovieByAsc() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "sortQuery", value: "Title Ascending" )]
        let urlComps = NSURLComponents(string: "http://192.168.81.118:8080/mobileweb/Android/getSortMovie")!
        urlComps.queryItems = queryItems as [URLQueryItem]?
        let URL = urlComps.url!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

                self.movies = [MOVIE]()
                for dictionary in json as! [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    let movie = MOVIE()
                    movie.movTitle = dictionary["TITLE"] as? String
                    movie.movImage = dictionary["PHOTO_DIR"] as? String
                    self.movies?.append(movie)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }

        }).resume()

    }

    func sortMovieByDesc() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "sortQuery", value: "Title Descending" )]
        let urlComps = NSURLComponents(string: "http://192.168.81.118:8080/mobileweb/Android/getSortMovie")!
        urlComps.queryItems = queryItems as [URLQueryItem]?
        let URL = urlComps.url!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

                self.movies = [MOVIE]()
                for dictionary in json as! [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    let movie = MOVIE()
                    movie.movTitle = dictionary["TITLE"] as? String
                    movie.movImage = dictionary["PHOTO_DIR"] as? String
                    self.movies?.append(movie)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }

        }).resume()

    }


    func fetchMovie() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.81.118:8080/mobileweb/Android/getMovie")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

                self.movies = [MOVIE]()
                for dictionary in json as! [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    let movie = MOVIE()
                    movie.movTitle = dictionary["TITLE"] as? String
                    movie.movImage = dictionary["PHOTO_DIR"] as? String
                    movie.movID = dictionary["ID"] as? String
                    self.movies?.append(movie)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }


        }).resume()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchControllerMovie.isActive && searchControllerMovie.searchBar.text != "" {
            return (filteredMovies?.count)!
        }
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return movies?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "MovieCollectionViewCell"
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MovieCollectionViewCell

        if searchControllerMovie.isActive && searchControllerMovie.searchBar.text != "" {
            cell?.movie = filteredMovies?[indexPath.row]
        } else {
        // Configure the cell
            cell?.movie = movies?[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell!
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Row:\(indexPath.row)")
//        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath);
//        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: cell)
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
            let movieDetail: MOVIE

            if searchControllerMovie.isActive && searchControllerMovie.searchBar.text != "" {
                movieDetail = (filteredMovies?[indexPath.item])!
            }
            else {
                movieDetail = (movies?[indexPath.row])!
            }
            let controller = segue.destination as! MovieDetailsViewController
            controller.movieDetail = movieDetail

        }

    }
}

extension MovieCollectionViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchTextMovie(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ2Se.png 2.https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRIsV.png

Comment: and movieDetail is always the correct MOVIE object when you print movieDetail here: controller.movieDetail = movieDetail. ?

Comment: I didn't get your point sir @rett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this line in , you forgot to add this line while filter data..

```
 func sortMovieByDesc(){
   for dictionary in json as! [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    let movie = MOVIE()
                    movie.movTitle = dictionary["TITLE"] as? String
                    movie.movImage = dictionary["PHOTO_DIR"] as? String
                    movie.movID = dictionary["ID"] as? String // this line

                    self.movies?.append(movie)
                }
}

func sortMovieByAsc(){
for dictionary in json as! [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    let movie = MOVIE()
                    movie.movTitle = dictionary["TITLE"] as? String
                    movie.movImage = dictionary["PHOTO_DIR"] as? String
                    movie.movID = dictionary["ID"] as? String // this line

                    self.movies?.append(movie)
                }

}
```

Comment: I'm a newbie here so right now (I need to gain 15 reputations) so that I can upvote your comment. Im sorry

Answer (score 0):

collectionViews do not use indexPath.row, they use indexPath.item.

**Change**

```
movieDetail = (movies?[indexPath.row])!
```

**To**

```
movieDetail = (movies?[indexPath.item])!
```

Comment: I already change it to (item) still when I sort the collection view I cant get the value of the selected cell